# What UK banks use card readers?

Tags: united-kingdom, online-banking, security

I'm with a UK bank that authenticates by sending a text message to a mobile phone number.

I don't like this at all and I would like to switch to a bank that uses a solution with a cardreader, so that payments need the physical card and the PIN code.

What UK banks use online banking authentication using a cardreader and PIN?

Answer (score 1):

A few of the major banks:

- Royal Bank of Scotland - [yes](http://personal.rbs.co.uk/personal/security-centre/stay-safe-online.html)
- Barclays - [optional service](http://www.barclays.co.uk/Helpsupport/UpgradetoPINsentry/P1242559314766)
- Halifax - [no](http://www.halifax.co.uk/aboutonline/security/protecting-you/) (they use automated phone calls)
- Lloyds - [no](http://www.lloydsbank.com/help-guidance/security/authentication-procedure.asp) (as with Halifax)
- Co-Op - [yes](http://www.co-operativebank.co.uk/global/security/card-reader)
- HSBC - [no](http://www.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/contact-and-support/security-centre/secure-key) (use a standalone code generator)
- Nationwide - [yes](http://www.nationwide.co.uk/support/security-centre/internet-banking-security/card-reader-and-security-questions) (technically not a bank)

Comment: I just want to add that NatWest (technically part of RBS) also have card readers.  I'm not sure which other RBS brands do though, or if all of them do.

Comment: @gabe3886 if memory serves, RBS invested a large amount into unifying the IT systems of their UK acquisitions, so thst they're mostly running branded fronts in a common platform. Similar security systems for online banking would fit with this...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I wasn't sure how far it reached, and didn't want to look like I was claiming credit for extending your answer.

Comment: HSBC now offers smartphone app as an alternative to its standalone code generator. I received a letter only last week inviting me to switch